# Must unital ring homomorphism be identity mapping?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Unital ring homomorphism is one that maps 1 to 1. So I reason it this way, $\phi(a) = \phi(\overbrace{1+...+1}^a)= \overbrace{\phi(1) + ... + \phi(1)}^a = \overbrace{1 + ... + 1}^a = a.$ Hence, it is an identity mapping. However, i don't think that it is true. What is wrong with my reasoning?

Comment: First of all, homomorphisms between two different rings can't be the identity map, because the identity map is a map from a set to itself. But this is wrong even if you are talking about homomorphisms of a ring with itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What does that say for an element if $a$ can't be written as $1+1+\cdots + 1$?

For instance, in the complex numbers? Or the rational numbers even?

What you've shown is that if $R$ is a unital ring, there is at most one unital homomorphism: $\mathbb Z\to R$. (It's a little more work, but you can show there is always such a homomorphism.)

This function is not "the identity." An identity function is one that maps a set to itself, and $R$ might not be $\mathbb Z$. The resulting homomorphism might not be injective, either. If it is injective, we say the ring has "characteristic zero."

There are maps from rings to themselves that are not identity maps. The most famous is complex conjugation: $f(a+bi)=a-bi$.

Comment: ok so it is not true for complex or rational number. But it is true in Z, right?

Comment: Any unital homomorphism from $\mathbb Z$ to itself is the identity, yes. There are unital homomorphisms from $\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ which are not identities nor isomorphisms.

Comment: is it not true when i map to other ring? like Q. I think it is still true. I can't see why the argument above will fail if the codomain is different

Comment: Basically, $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ describe *all* rings for which every element $a$ can be written as $1+1+\cdots+1$.

Comment: No map from $\mathbb Z$ to $\mathbb Q$ is "the identity." But there is always a *unique* unital homomorphism from $\mathbb Z$ to any ring. But that map is not always one-to-one.

Comment: what do u mean by "no map from Z to Q is "the identity"". I think it is still injective, just not surjective. Which part of my argument above will fail if codomain is Q? Must identity mapping be surjective?

Comment: The identity function maps a set $S$ to itself. There is no "identity function" from $S$ to $T$ if $T$ is a different set. @user136266

Comment: @user136266: It will probably be clearer to your readers if you refer to the injective ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Q} $ as the *inclusion* map rather than an identity map.

Comment: Clearer and correct. :) @hardmath